# Join master table's data to a key/value table data in one SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot, key-value

I have a table called `Contacts` that contains the columns

1. Id
2. FirstName
3. LastName

I have another table called `ContactsExtra`. It has the following columns:

1. Id
2. ContactId (FK refers to Contacts Id)
3. PropertyId (FK refers to Properties Id)
4. PropertyValue

This is a Key/Value table that stores some extra contact properties. E.g. if contact has a *Salary* property there is a record in this table for all *Contacts* that stores the *Salary* value.

All Properties (whether they are in the main `Contacts` table or not) are stored in a separate table called `Properties`. In this table, those properties that come from `Contacts` (FirstName and LastName) are locked. But the user can add or remove custom properties (these ones are not locked). The value of these new properties will be stored in `ContactsExtra`.

The `Properties` table contains the following columns:

1. Id
2. Name

What I would like to do is to display all the contact information using one SELECT. So e.g. in the above case there will be a result with columns *Id*,*FirstName*,*LastName* and also *Salary*. The first three come from Contacts and the last comes from the Key/Value table. How can I join these information together?

Comment: Are you looking simply to add that one extra column on (salary) or for a more generic query to get all the properties in a single row?

Comment: @MarkLeiber Salary is just an example. I would like to get all the properties in a single row.

Comment: Unless you can provide some details about the table structures and some sample data there isn't much we can do. This is a relatively simple query with structures. I would suggest creating this at sqlfiddle.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Contacts.FirstName,
    Contacts.LastName,
    Properties.Name,
    ContactsExtra.PropertyValue
FROM
    Contacts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactsExtra ON Contacts.Id = ContactsExtra.ContactId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Properties ON ContactsExtra.PropertyId = Properties.Id
```

Okay, here's the update with a PIVOT (not UNPIVOT as I first thought)...

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        Contacts.FirstName,
        Contacts.LastName,
        Properties.Name,
        ContactsExtra.PropertyValue
    FROM
        Contacts
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactsExtra ON Contacts.Id = ContactsExtra.ContactId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Properties ON ContactsExtra.PropertyId = Properties.Id
    ) DerivedPivotable
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(PropertyValue)
        FOR [Name] IN (<comma delimited list of values from your Properties.Name field, without string markup>)
        --FOR [Name] IN (Salary, Height, Status, SSN) --example row
    ) Pivoted
```

Please check against your data - I expect the output to be something like...

```
FirstName   LastName    Salary  Height  Status  SSN
-----------------------------------------------------------
Jane        Doe         NULL    5'7"    Single  NULL
Bob         Smith       70,000  6'1"    NULL    123-45-6789
```

The use of MAX is a bit of a kludge because it has to be an aggregate function there.  The assumption is being made that there is only one value in the ContactsExtra table for each combination of user and property.

Comment: Just saw the follow-up comment about getting all the properties in a single row.  I think that's going to be an UNPIVOT - will update when I have something...

Comment: That would be great. Thank you! Yes. I think it takes an `Unpivot`.

Comment: Updated, as promised.

Comment: Don't have my work laptop with me. Will check tomorrow as soon as I can. Thanks.